# Azure Api Management convert XML to JSON policy inbound

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to define a policy in API to convert XML to JSON. Our back end API currently supports JSON only but I want clients to be able to post XML. I can successfully have JSON converted to XML as an outbound policy, but the inbound policy simply results in an empty post.

The working outbound policy is:

```
<outbound>
    <base />
    <json-to-xml apply="content-type-json" consider-accept-header="true" />
</outbound>
```

The inbound policy is effectively the reverse:

```
<inbound>
    <xml-to-json kind="direct" apply="content-type-xml" consider-accept-header="true" />
</inbound>
```

I have created a new test API pointing to a requestbin instance so I can inspect the request. I create a simply XML request in postman and set the Content-Type to text/xml, but the request in requestbin always shows an empty post.

I've tried debugging using the useful comment from @miao-jiang below. The trace shows that the policy is applied but that the content length has been removed. I wonder if this might be the root cause?

2Relevant entry from the trace log:

```
{"source":"xml-to-json", "timestamp":"2015-09-08T19:51:01.5919446Z", elapsed":"00:00:00.2116541", "data":"XML-to-JSON policy was applied. Original Content-Length header was removed as its value was invalidated. Content-Type header was set to 'application/json'."}
```

Here you can see that policy is applied, however no json is present in the request.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the issue using the API Inspector? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-api-inspector/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I've run a trace and can see the policy is applied but still no content in the final request.

Comment: Please send the trace to apimgmt at microsoft dotcom, we'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you - email with trace result and link to this post sent.. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am having the exact same problem. When I perform a conversion from `xml-to-json` in the outbound policies it works fine, both `json-to-xml` and `xml-to-json`, however in the inbound policy it results as an empty body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue. Can you please confirm if your backend supports Transfer-Encoding: chunked?

What happens in the xml-to-json policy is that it removes your original content-length header, and replace it with Transfer-Encoding:chunked, because the length will be different after the transformation and we cannot predict the length.

When I tested with a backend that supports Transfer-Encoding:chunked, it worked properly. When I tested with another backend that does not support it, I saw the same behavior you described. So I was wondering if that’s what happened to you as well.

Comment: Thanks Miao. This does indeed appear to be the issue. I haven't managed to get the backend to support chunked transfer encoding yet, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @phoenixx Any HTTP/1.1 compliant server [MUST](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-4.1) implement chunked transfer encoding. You shouldn't have to do anything different than normal on your server.

Comment: Thanks @darrelmiller. I'm using NancyFX on top of iis and it just never seems to receive the body when transfer encoding is set as chunked. IIS has been set to allow chunked transfer so there's obviously something else going on here.

Comment: @phoenix Most of the Nancy folks are probably sleeping at the moment but I pointed them to this question via Twitter so maybe they will have answers in the morning.